# Google map marker: raise on drag and animation on drop?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Before v3, marker was sightly raise while it was being dragging, and it has a bounce effect at the moment mouse has released (drop). Now, its not happening. Where is problem?

```
Marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
          draggable:true,
          icon:'img/markerA.png',
          shadow:'img/shadow50.png',
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking for this answer to as I like the animation when dragging a marker.

Turns out there are more animations available then there are in the google.maps.Animation namspace.

For your example you need to set an animation on the dragstart and dragend events like so:

```
Marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
          draggable:true,
          icon:'img/markerA.png',
          shadow:'img/shadow50.png',
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });

google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragstart", function (event) {
   Marker.setAnimation(3); // raise
});

google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function (event) {
    Marker.setAnimation(4); // fall
});
```